# python pandas dataframe assignment error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, copy

A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

```
data1['other_id_phone'][i]= 1
```

I am trying to let the 'nan' = 0,numbers = 1,
just a sign
my poor english,all right
pls help,i dont know.where am i wrong.THX!

below is my code

[image]

Comment: Sorry are your nan values the string 'nan' or `NaN`?

Comment: Also don't post links to images, you should post raw data, code to create the df, what you tried, any errors, and the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you can do this without a loop:

```
data1['other_id_phone'] = np.where(data1['other_id_phone'].isnull(), 0, 1)
```

Secondly the error comes from [chained indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy):

```
data1['other_id_phone'][i] = some_value
```

You should use the modern indexing methods such as `loc`, `iloc` to index the df so it operates on a view:

```
data1.loc[i, 'other_id_phone'] = some_value
```

you could also rewrite to:

```
data1['other_id_phone'] = data1['other_id_phone'].notnull().astype(int)
```

if your data you're replacing is the string `'nan'` then you need:

```
data1['other_id_phone'] = np.where(data1['other_id_phone'] == 'nan', 0, 1)
```

Comment: goddamn.you are awesome.do you have a wechat? i am a new guy but a very man want to improve code ability,actually. thx my friend!

Comment: I don't do social media, I suggest looking at posts on SO, a couple blogs such as this: http://www.gregreda.com/tag/pandas.html and the book: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023784.do although the book is a bit dated

Comment: thx my bro! i have a nice try on SO,one day , i will be the one who can help others without a name like Leifeng. you know leifeng?A Chinese hero mordel